# mysql update with condition: fails

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to make a simple table with MySQL that satisfies the below condition.

update the result from Outcomes data to 'sunk' if the ship was built-in 'Japan'

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried several codes but they all failed.

Here's the code I've been trying

```
update Outcomes
    set result = 'sunk' 
where ship = (
                select name 
                from Ships 
                    natural join Classes as A 
                where Classes.country = 'Japan' 
                and Outcomes.ship =  A.name
            );
```

I added data input query for the case you might need it.

```
create table Classes(
    Class varchar(20), 
    type char(20), 
    country varchar(20), 
    numGuns int, 
    bore int, 
    displacement int,
    primary key(Class)
);

create table Ships(
    name varchar(20), 
    Class varchar(20), 
    launched int,
    primary key(name),
    foreign key(Class) references Classes (Class)
);

create table Outcomes(
    ship varchar(20), 
    battle varchar(20), 
    result varchar(10),
    foreign key(battle) references Battles(Name),
    foreign key(ship) references Ships(name)
);

insert into Classes values 
('Bismark', 'bb', 'Germany', 8, 15, 42000),
('Iowa', 'bb', 'USA', 9, 16, 46000),
('Kongo', 'bc', 'Japan', 8, 14, 32000),
('North Carolina', 'bb', 'USA', 9, 16, 37000),
('Renown', 'bc', 'Gt. Britain', 6, 15, 32000),
('Revenge', 'bb', 'Gt. Britain', 8,15, 29000),
('Tennessee', 'bb', 'USA', 12, 14, 32000),
('Yamato', 'bb', 'Japan', 9, 18, 65000);

insert into Ships values
('Prince of Wales', 'Tennessee', 1921),
('Bismark', 'Bismark', 1915),
('Duke of York', 'Kongo', 1914),
('Iowa', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Kirishima', 'Kongo', 1915),
('Kongo', 'Kongo', 1913),
('Fuso', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Yamashiro', 'Yamato', 1942),
('California', 'Iowa', 1943),
('North Carolina', 'North Carolina', 1941),
('Renown', 'Renown', 1916),
('Hood', 'Renown', 1916),
('Scharnhorst', 'Revenge', 1916),
('Revenge', 'Revenge', 1916),
('King George V', 'Revenge', 1916),
('South Dakota', 'Revenge', 1916),
('Tennessee', 'Tennessee', 1920),
('Washington', 'North Carolina', 1941),
('West Virginia', 'Iowa', 1943),
('Yamato', 'Yamato', 1941);

insert into Outcomes values 
('Bismark', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk'),
('California', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Duke of York', 'North Cape', 'ok'),
('Duke of York', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Fuso', 'Surigao Strait', 'sunk'),
('Hood', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk'),
('King George V', 'North Atlantic', 'ok'),
('Kirishima', 'Guadalcanal', 'sunk'),
('Prince of Wales', 'North Atlantic', 'damaged'),
('Prince of Wales', 'North Cape', 'ok'),
('Scharnhorst', 'North Cape', 'sunk'),
('South Dakota', 'Guadalcanal', 'damaged'),
('Tennessee', 'Surigao Strait', 'sunk'),
('Washington', 'Guadalcanal', 'ok'),
('West Virginia', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok'),
('Yamashiro', 'Surigao Strait', 'ok');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct UPDAtE must be  The Name of the ship comes from ships and not Classes.

```
update Outcomes
        set result = 'sunk' 
    where ship = (
                    select name 
                    from Ships B
                        natural join Classes as A 
                    where A.country = 'Japan' 
                    and Outcomes.ship =  B.name
                );
```

See example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=999573123e2a739389e40108dca130a5

Answer (score 1):

You could try a joined update:

```
update Outcomes
join   Ships
on     Outcomes.ship = Ships.name
join   Classes
on     Classes.class = Ships.class
set    Outcomes.result = 'sunk'
where  Classes.country = 'Japan'
```

Where I see your mistake, is that you join `and Outcomes.ship =  A.name` instead of `and Ships.class =  A.name` (with `A` being the aliased name for `Classes`). Also, you refer to your `Classes` table by its actual name (`Classes`) although you aliased it (`A`). This is not allowed, as far as I am aware:

```
update Outcomes
    set result = 'sunk' 
where ship = (
                select name 
                from Ships 
                    natural join Classes as A 
                where Classes.country = 'Japan' <<< Here you refer to Classes instead of A
                and Outcomes.ship =  A.name <<< This doesn't make sense to me
            );
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me! But unfortunately for some reason, I got an error for <join on> recommendation. It says ': ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Classes.name' in 'on clause'

Comment: Oh, i see: It's `Classes.class`